Is there a reason an execute pipeline cannot work in a switch activity?
I have a pipeline that has a switch activity - Quite simply, one of the paths is to run an execute pipeline.
I know the path works if I put a Wait in there only but if I put an execute pipeline, the pipeline fails to run.
It instantly errors with a Run Failed - Failed to run pipeline [pipeline with the switch activity]
Nothing in Monitor as it fails to even get that far
Is this a bug? Or can a switch path not have an execute pipeline activity?
Thanks

Can you click the execute pipeline activity and show its settings?

check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with


Failed to run pipeline

This error occurs when the execute pipeline activities inside switch activity do not have the invoked pipeline details.

To resolve this, add the pipeline in the invoked pipeline as shown in the above image.
